# Suppose you have a simple host running Virtualbox with NAT networking and do malware testing on it, how safe are you?

Tags: malware, virtualization

So, just a single windows host attached to the router and a virtual machine running  on it. No shared folders or clipboard. Just testing your average malware.

Note that this question talks about just a single PC connected to a router, without any fancy file sharing enabled via network (It can have stuff like torrents and download managers, but not anything like a shared folder in the network).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use virtual machines when examining malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/), [How can I safely test malware in a VM?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171649/), [Does a Virtual Machine stop malware from doing harm?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9011/) and [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+testing+malware+virtual+machine). Also note that with just NAT the VM has access to your internal network and can for example attack the router.